# Docker machine / Docker link returns different container IP on Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, docker, digital-ocean, docker-machine

I created a Droplet on DigitalOcean using Docker machine.

When running two containers and linking them this way from Jenkins:

```
/bin/bash/eval "$(docker-machine env deployment)"
/bin/bash -c "docker run -d -t --name container1 -p 5000:5000 image1"
/bin/bash -c "docker run -d -t --name container2 -p 5001:5001 --link container1:container1 image2"
```

And then `docker inspect container1 | grep "IPAddress"` I get `172.17.0.51`.
But when I run the Node.js application in container2 which calls  `process.env.CONTAINER1_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR` it resolves to
`172.17.0.7:5000` when I call container2 from its public IP (of the DO droplet) which causes to return `No route to host`.

When I `exec` into container2 and run `node process.env.CONTAINER1_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR` it returns `172.17.0.51`.

If I ssh into the host using another user, `docker inspect container2 | grep "IPAddress"` also returns `172.17.0.52` instead of `172.17.0.51`.

Why does the Node.js application return the wrong IP address whereas running Node.js on the command line returns a different and correct IP address?

Update:
If I run the containers locally on the Jenkins machine without docker-machine and DO, everything works fine.

Comment: I think you need to go over your problem statement and make sure you are checking the correct ports. I understand so far: container2 has IP `172.17.0.51`; container1 is `172.17.0.7`; now can you explain this _"when I call conatiner2 from its public IP (of the DO droplet)"_ - how are you calling it and from where? - also; are you complete sure about this statement: _when I exec into container2 it returns 172.17.0.51 for CONTAINER1_PORT_5000_TCP_ADDR_?

Comment: I fixed the statement. Container1 has IP `172.17.0.51` if I run `node process.env.CONTAINER1_PORT_5000_TCP_ADD` from the console. If I call the Node.js application in container2 from the droplets public IP which tries to access container1, it returns `172.17.0.7` instead of `172.17.0.51` for container1.

Comment: Unfortunately, without actual images we can all run in the problem statement and confirm the issues, the answer to "what happened" can only be speculation.

Comment: You can find both images here: https://hub.docker.com/u/alexzeitler/customerservice/ https://hub.docker.com/u/alexzeitler/customerui/ . customerui is container2 and customerservice is container1